# Integrating FirebaseUI Auth in react native

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I've managed to (almost) integrate FirebaseUI Auth in to my react-native app in iOS. I can click on a react-native button, load the firebase auth flow, and send a callback to a react-native javascript function once logged in. I can call the function with the firebase user's UID or refreshToken.

I'm stuck trying to make use of this in react native though. Is it possible to log in a user to firebase in react-native by using just a UID or the refresh token?

EDIT: adding some of the code, though I'm sure it could use some refactoring unrelated to this problem:

in ios folder

## in AppDelegate.m

```
FUIAuth *authUI;
RCTResponseSenderBlock rnOnLogin;

- (void)authUI:(FUIAuth *)authUI didSignInWithUser:(nullable FIRUser *)user error:(nullable NSError *)error {
  // Implement this method to handle signed in user or error if any.
   RCTLogInfo(@"Logged in (app delegate)");
  if (user == NULL) {
    RCTLogInfo(@"Null User");
  } else {
    RCTLogInfo(@"Got User (app delegate)");
    RCTLogInfo(user.uid);
    RCTLogInfo(user.providerData);
    // HERE I CAN PASS INFO ABOUT USER TO REACT NATIVE
    rnOnLogin(@[[NSNull null], user.providerData]);
  }
  if (error != NULL) {
    RCTLogInfo(@"Got Error  (app delegate)");
    RCTLogInfo(error);
  }
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
  RCTLogInfo(@"openURL application (app delegate)");
  return [[FUIAuth defaultAuthUI] handleOpenURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication];
}
```

## in RCTFirebaseAuthUI.m

```
@implementation RCTFirebaseAuthUI

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();

UINavigationController *authViewController;
extern FUIAuth *authUI;
extern RCTResponseSenderBlock rnOnLogin;

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(showLogin:(nonnull RCTResponseSenderBlock )onLogin)
{
  RCTLogInfo(@"showLogin method");

  if(authViewController == nil) {
   authViewController = [authUI authViewController];
   authViewController.delegate = authUI;
  }

  rnOnLogin = onLogin;

  UIWindow *window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
  UIViewController *rootViewController = window.rootViewController;
  [rootViewController presentViewController:authViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

in react native

## in ProfileScreen.js

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

export default class ProfileScreen extends Component {

  logout = () => {
    firebase.auth().signOut()
  }

  setUid = (error, token) => {
    console.log('rn')
    console.log(token)

    // HERE I NEED TO LOGIN THE USER TO REACT NATIVE's FIREBASE
    // firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(token).catch((error) =>
    //  console.log(error)
    //)
  }

  pushLoginScreen = () => {
    var loginUI = NativeModules.FirebaseAuthUI
    loginUI.showLogin(this.setUid)
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      user: null
    };
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      this.setState({
        user: user
      })
    })
  }

  render() {
    console.log('render profile')
    console.log(this.state.user)
    let user = this.state.user
    if (user !== null) {
      return (
        <View>
           <Text>{user.email}</Text>
        </View>
      )
    } else {
      return (
        <View>
          <Text>Profile</Text>
          <Button title="Login" onPress={this.pushLoginScreen} />
        </View>
      )
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain more what you are doing? It does not seem to be clear. Some code would help.

Comment: Sorry @bojeil ....code added

Comment: May have a solution... I think I'll need to treat the ios code as a firebase custom auth server. I'll use a private key to generate a JWT token, pass that to react native, and use firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(token)

Comment: @MattyB the solution you mention ```firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(token))``` works? so is you question solved?

Comment: @FrancoRondini It technically works but it's a big hack